# message driven bean - notification when deployed?

Tags: jboss, ejb, jboss-mdb

is it possible to get notified inside the bean (mdb in this case) that its deployment procedure has just finished?

Comment: May I ask you one thing: what do you want to do?

Comment: sure. i'm trying to write a MDB being activated by quartz. looks easy, but I need to fetch its activation config from "master" node via JMS message. basically, what I wanted to do was to ask "master" for configuration each time MDB deploys on given "slave" node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that when `setMessageDrivenContext` is called, that's your bean deployed - you know that the container has a context and has assigned it to your MDB.

The problem with your design is that MDBs are passive components, they're not supposed to *do* anything until a message gets delivered to them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure once the constructor is complete it's considered to be "deployed."

Okay, to address the downvote, from the [Jave EE API documentation](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/ejb/MessageDrivenBean.html), you have two lifecycle methods available to you:

```
void ejbRemove()
      A container invokes this method before it ends the life of the message-driven object.

void setMessageDrivenContext(MessageDrivenContext ctx)
      Set the associated message-driven context.
```

Unfortunately, that's it.